# angular 2 after build proxy config not found

Tags: angular

Hi after build for prod my proxy is not working. When we send the request to google map api service. it is not working
code is as shown below

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8000",
        "secure": false
    },
    "/googleapi/*": {
        "target": {
            "host": "maps.googleapis.com",
            "protocol": "https:"
        },
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/googleapi": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi still i am not getting any response